# How to get reference from an html element in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I just started with `nodejs` and since I can't reference the `app.js` to the html file since I'm actually starting that `js file` with the nodejs. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work like that. I think you are trying to use the app.js file of a node app as if it was a simple script reference in the html with the  tags.

NodeJS runs in the server and the HTML file runs in the client. The server script you are running can provide data to the client, client-server must be "connected" with an API.

If you are using vue or react for the Front-End, check Axios as a library for fetching data via API.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-access-elements-in-the-dom)

It's a detailed and great explanation for what you need.